# Error al compilar proyecto PocketPC

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

Tengo el siguiente error:

> Error 1 Error de registro o implementación: 0x8973190d. Error al abrir el archivo '%CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES%\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\Devices\wce500\ARMV4i\sqlce.ppc.wce5.armv4i.CAB'. Error 0x80070002: El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado. Device Connectivity Component

y pues el `.CAB sqlce.ppc.wce5.armv4i.CAB` si se encuentra en la dirección que dice arriba

¿Cómo puedo solucionar este error? Estoy desarrollando en `Visual Studio 2008` y base de datos `SqlCompact 3.5`

**Actualizació**

ya solucionado el problema anterior, me sale este nuevo error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> File or assembly name 'System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=3.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3BE235DF1C8D2AD3', or one of its dependencies, was not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El modo que solucione el problema fue desistalando todos los sql compact que tenia en el equipo y descargarlos nuevamente desde la pagina de microsoft 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/search/result.aspx?q=sql+server+compact+3.5+sp2&form=dlc

tanto para SP1 como para SP2

y con eso solucione este problema

Answer (score 1):

Actualiza el `SQL Server Compact 3.5` con su respectivo `SP1`: https://www.microsoft.com/es-ES/download/details.aspx?id=17020

Con respecto al archivo `sqlce30.ppc.wce5.armv4i.CAB`, intenta copiarlo en el dispositivo o emulador.